# Why in_array returns 1?

Tags: php

Here is my line of code

```
<?php

echo in_array('test', [0,1]);

?>
```

And it returns **1**.
The string 'test' is not present in the array, and yet it returns true.

Thanks in adnvace

Comment: Your title says `is_array` and your code has `in_array`.

Answer (score 5):

Use Strict type by passing third parameter **`in_array`** function

```
<?php
    echo in_array('test',[0,1],true);
?>
```